# Calling multiple methods in their own threads

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

So I have 3 methods, `walk()`, `jog()`, and `run()`. I want to run each methods in their own separate threads. Most of the questions similar to this say that the code/method goes under `public void run()` but I want just one method going there at a time. Is there a way to do that without putting all of them under `public void run()`?

Comment: I'm very new at java programming so please bear with me. I apologize if my question does not make sense.

Comment: You could add some code to help clarify.  If you want to use a `Thread` class, I don't think there's any way to do it without `Runnable` or `Callable`.  Note that in Java 8 method references give you syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of an exercise class using the (old) Thread class to walk, jog or run using different methods. All three are executed in different threads by creating a new instance of the class for each exercise type

```
public class Excercise implements Runnable {
  enum ExcerciseType {
    WALKING,
    JOGGING,
    RUNNING
  };

  private final ExcerciseType excerciseType;
  public Thread thread;

  public Excercise(ExcerciseType type) {
    excerciseType = type;
  }

  public void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      switch (excerciseType) {
        case WALKING:
          walk();
          break;
        case JOGGING:
          jog();
          break;
        default:
          running();
          break;
      } 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      return;
    }
  }

  public void walk() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Started walking");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Done walking");
  }

  public void jog() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Started jogging");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Done jogging");
  }

  public void running() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Started running");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Done running");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Excercise e1 = new Excercise(ExcerciseType.WALKING);
    e1.start();

    Excercise e2 = new Excercise(ExcerciseType.JOGGING);
    e2.start();

    Excercise e3 = new Excercise(ExcerciseType.RUNNING);
    e3.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey this looks really good! Similar to what I'm doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java8+, you could use Lambda-expressions:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> walk());
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> jog());
Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> run());
```

And moreover, you might replace them with Method-references

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(this::walk);
Thread t2 = new Thread(this::jog);
Thread t3 = new Thread(this::run);
```

Comment: I currently have one java file that has all 3 methods and in that java file, I am calling all 3 methods in the main method of that java file. I wasnt sure if I could call the 3 methods in their own separate thread to save cpu time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what Lambda-expressions are yet (as you said you're new), you can also create an instance of a Thread object and then do whatever you want within each object's run method. E.g:

```
Thread walk = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("walking");
    }
};
walk.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Thread` class is old; since Java 7 the classes under `java.util.concurrent` are preferred.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
List<Future<?>> result = executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(
                                 ()->walk(),
                                 ()->jog(),
                                 ()->run()));
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: This looks complicated but I'll read some documentation and see if I can implement it. Thank you!